# Python - Bytes impicity converted to int when iterating in zip()

Tags: python, python-3.x

My `bytes` is getting converted to an `int` but I don't know exactly where?

Take this example

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

>>> a = 'a'
>>> b = b'b'
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> z = zip(a,b)
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> for a,b in z:
    print(type(a),type(b))
<class 'str'> <class 'int'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'int'>
```

I guess this is some kind of **coercion** but what triggers it? is doesn't appear to be using the zip iterator? as calling `z.__next__()` does not cause the conversion.

Thanks

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 and that is not happening. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @R.Q. 3.6.1 win32 its in the output above the console stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes)) says a `bytes` is a sequence of integers. Further down the documentation of `zip` ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)) says, that zip iterates over sequences. That is why `b` becomes of type `int`.

You can see that by doing the following:

```
>>> b = b'b'
>>> for i in b:
...    print(type(i), i)
<class 'int'> 98
```

Notice please, that by using `a` and `b` as loop variables you overwrite the original `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense now!